# Python+Firebase memory leak?

Tags: python, firebase

Recently, I've encountered what seems to be a memory leak which I am unable to find its source.
I'm using Python 3.4 with [Firebase library](http://ozgur.github.io/python-firebase/)  and "requests 2.7.0"

This is the flow of my code:
My program is running with a `while true` loop.
I have an object `Foo` which is being re-declared every iteration (`foo = Foo()`).
When Foo is being initialized, it opens multiple async calls to firebase (`fb. get_async()`).
When the call returns it saves the result into self fields of `Foo`.
The firebase trees it's calling are quite heavy.
I do make sure that after every iteration foo is being deleted and I even call gc.collect().
However, it seems that the memory of the process is growing after every iteration, until the computer gets stuck or the process crashes.

I'm using tracemalloc to see where the large objects are being created, and I get this output:

Additionally, I'm using gc.get_objects() to see what that object is, and surprisingly I found it to be a huge list that holds tuples of (number,string) of this form:
0000000 = {tuple} (208, (('C:\Python34\lib\copy.py', 246),))
0000001 = {tuple} (208, (('C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py', 251),))
etc..

I was wondering if you have any idea about the source or going around this problem.
Thank you
Guy

Comment: Instead of describing your code, create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem. But even with that this may be better as a bug report on the github repo, unless you've isolated the problem to a code snippet in that library and want our help finding the final cause in that snippet.

Comment: Forgot to mention - I was unable to reproduce the problem with a minimal code. What do you recommend?

Comment: Anybody? I'll appreciate your help